# Filling bars in barplot with textiles rather than color in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to fill bars in a barplot using different textiles rather than color.

I know how to fill the bars with different patterns of lines like this:

```
aaa <- c(1,2,3,4)
barplot(aaa, density = c(4,4,4,4), angle = c(45, 90, 180, -45))
```

This will give me something like this:

```
                       ___
4|                    |\\\|
 |              ___   |\\\|
3|             |___|  |\\\|
 |             |___|  |\\\|
2|       ___   |___|  |\\\|
 |      |||||  |___|  |\\\|
1|___   |||||  |___|  |\\\|
 |///|  |||||  |___|  |\\\|
0|///|__|||||__|___|__|\\\|_
   1      2      3      4
```

I am not sure how to do this with other types of fills (for example shapes such as *, squares, colored dots, triangles, etc). Or if this can actually be done at all.

At the moment, I am using the igraph library, and am not too sure if there are any other packages that may allow me to use other types of fills.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Cross-hatching](http://www.perceptualedge.com/blog/?p=1756) is bad juju.  Could you put the bar names on the bars directly and avoid this practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**`plotrix`**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotrix/index.html) package provides [`rectFill`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plotrix/docs/rectFill) and [`barp`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plotrix/docs/barp) functions, which allow to fill the bars with custom shapes.

`barp` produces barplots and calls `rectFill` to fill them with symbols. The symbols can be specified using default `pch` parameters ([reference chart](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html)), or via custom string, see the examples below.

```
# install the package
install.packages('plotrix')

# examples with varying pch parameters
require(plotrix)
a <- 1:4
barp(t(a), pch=t(1:4))
barp(t(a), pch=t(c("*","$","~","@")))
```

Unfortunately `barp` is not very flexible:

1. The data has to be supplied in a matrix format to specify varying symbols. The columns of the matrix should correspond with the sequence of pch parameters. Hence the need for `t()` in the current examples.
2. Once `pch` is specified, the plot becomes black and white. `rectFill` function allows to control the colour of the symbols via `pch.col`, but the `barp` doesn't allow this option. To address this, I added the ellipsis (`...`) to the `barp` source code to be able to pass further arguments to the `rectFill` function. The modified code (`barp2`) is available [here](https://gist.github.com/tleja/8592929).

Example using modified code:

```
# load the barp2 function
require(devtools)
source_gist("https://gist.github.com/tleja/8592929")

# run the barp2 function
require(plotrix)
a <- 1:4
barp2(t(a), pch=t(1:4), pch.col=1:4)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** It appears that the most recent version of the package may have a bug, since some users are having trouble reproducing the plots. If that happens, please try installing the earlier version of `plotrix` using the code below:

```
require(devtools)
install_url("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/plotrix/plotrix_3.5-2.tar.gz")
```

Comment: When I try the code you have provided, all I'm getting is an x and y axis that both go up to 4, and only one white bar at (1, 1). This is after I run the barp2 function you provided as a link, and then the final barp2 code from above. Is this what is meant to be produced from this code?

Comment: @Warrior, `barp2` should produce the same figure as you can see above. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce your problem. Do you see an error message? Does the original `barp` function work? To isolate the problem, please restart your R session, load the `plotrix` package, then the `barp2` function, and try `barp2(t(1:4), pch=t(1:4), pch.col=1:4)`.

Comment: @Warrior, there may be an issue with the package itself. Please load  `plotrix` package and let me know if you can reproduce the example code at the bottom of the documentation page, available at `?rectFill`. You should be able to obtain a plot of stacked multi-coloured rectangles with different symbols. If that doesn't work, please install the older version of `plotrix`, as shown in the most recent edit of the answer. Also, remember to install the `devtools` first: `install.packages("devtools")`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46182/discussion-between-twl-and-warrior)

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure something like below can be adapted:

```
aaa <- c(1,2,3,4)
bp <- barplot(aaa,col="white")

fillbars <- function(height,bp,bg,size,spacing) {
  coords <- data.frame(bp-0.5,bp+0.5,0,height)
  invisible(
    apply(
      coords,
      1,
      function(d) {
        do.call(clip,unname(as.list(d)))
        x <- seq(d[1],d[2],by=spacing)
        y <- seq(d[3],d[4],by=spacing)
        xy <- expand.grid(x,y)
        symbols(
          xy,
          circles=rep(size,nrow(xy)),
          inches=FALSE,
          bg=bg,
          add=TRUE
        )
      }
    )
  )
}

fillbars(height=aaa,bp=bp,bg="red",size=0.06,spacing=0.3)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How can this be modified so that each bar has a different fill rather than the same one for all of them?