# 'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 13 != 10 error in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, devtools, plotrix

I have a data frame, df, that looks this this:

```
      a   b   c   d   e   f   g    h     i    j   k   l    m
1a    4   4   3   4   3   4   3   4.0   4.0   4   4   4   3.9
1b    9   9   9   9   9   9   9   8.1   8.8   9   9   9   8.5
1c    8   8   9   8   9   8   8   8.0   9.0   8   9   8   8.3
1d    8   8   8   9   8   9   8   8.0   8.0   8   8   8   8.5
1e    4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4.0   4.0   4   4   4   4.0
2a    3   4   3   4   3   4   3   4.0   3.0   4   3   4   3.8
2b    8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8.0   8.0   8   8   8   8.0
2c    8   8   8   8   8   8   8   9.0   8.0   9   8   8   8.3
2d    8   9   8   8   8   9   8   9.0   8.0   9   8   9   8.0
2e    4   3   4   3   4   4   4   4.0   4.0   4   4   3   3.9
```

I am using the `plotrix` and `devtools` packages, and have already installed them both, and the `barp2` function like this:

```
# install the packages and load the barp2 function
install.packages('plotrix')
install.packages('devtools')
install_url("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/plotrix/plotrix_3.5-2.tar.gz")
source_gist("https://gist.github.com/tleja/8592929")

# load the packages
library(plotrix)
library(devtools)
```

The modified code (`barp2`) that I'm using is available [here](https://gist.github.com/tleja/8592929).

I am trying to plot the data in the data frame, provided above, like this:

```
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 6))
barp2(df, pch=t(c(0:4, 7:14)), names.arg=rownames(df), legend.lab=colnames(df),
    ylab="y label", main="main")
```

I am using the [reference chart](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html), to fill the bars of the plot.

I want the rownames of df to be the x axis labels, and the colnames of df to be in a legend.

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error in axis(1, at = x, labels = names.arg, cex.axis = cex.axis) : 
    'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 13 != 10
```

I understand that this is because `rownames(df)` has a length of 10 and `colnames(df)` has a length of 13 (which are clearly not equal), but I am not sure how to fix this problem, so that the data in the data frame is displayed in a barplot.

Or if I swap the columns and rows around using `t(df)`, like this:

```
barp2(t(df), pch=t(c(0:4, 7:11)), names.arg=rownames(df), legend.lab=colnames(df),
ylab="y label", main="main")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in seq.default(x1[frect] + xinc[frect]/2, x2[frect] - xinc[frect]/2,  : 
    wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

I have no idea what this error means or why I get it.

Sorry I can't provide an image of what it should look like, but hopefully you get the basic idea of it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `t()` on the argument to pch just looks wrong.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat - Even if I remove the `t()` on the `pch`, I still get the same error. I had included the `t()` because _the data has to be supplied in a matrix format to specify varying symbols. The columns of the matrix should correspond with the sequence of `pch` parameters_. As someone had said on this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323798/filling-bars-in-barplot-with-textiles-rather-than-color-in-r).