# Filled rectangle in R

Tags: r, plot, rect

I would like to know which function would allow me to draw filled rectangles like (or with different other fills like dots or dotted/dashed lines)

[image]

I am aware of the function `rect()`, but that function allows only for color filling.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The first answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323798/filling-bars-in-barplot-with-textiles-rather-than-color-in-r) may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, it doesn't really work for me. The reason is that I need to draw a rectangle at specific coordinates on a plot. The functions suggested in that link do not allow for that.

Comment: In the answer, there is a link to `rectFill`. In `rectFill` you set "`x1,y1,x2,y2 Rectangle limits as in rect`", i.e coordinates.

Comment: I think `rect` can do other fills too: what about `plot(1:10); rect(1,4,2,5, density=20, angle=45)`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try density in the rect function - an example

```
   plot(c(100, 200), c(300, 450), type= "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
   rect(110, 300, 175, 350, density = 5, border = "red")
```

you can use lty to have different types of borders and shading

example -

```
  rect(110, 300, 175, 350, density = 5, border = "red", lty =2)
```